# Analytics not working after duplicating a Sitecore installation to a second server

Tags: experience-analytics, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I'm trying to duplicate my Sitecore installation from CM1 to CM2. After I completed my installation on CM1, I have applied the following steps:

1. Copy wwwroot site folder from CM1 to CM2.
2. Copy Solr indexes folders from CM1 to CM2
3. Create new Website in IIS on CM2.

My new site is working fine except for Sitecore Experience Analytics.

Do you know if there is any other setting I should apply to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Question 1: why? Question 2: Are you using the same databases? Did you copy the xConnect certificates from CM1 to CM2?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? A distributed CM environment or a new separate CM instance for a different website?

Comment: @ChrisAuer  our  goal is to have high availability  environment. yes im using the same  databases , for the Xconnect i export the certificate from CM 1 then i installed in CM 2 is there any other setting i should apply for the certificate   ?

Comment: @RichardSeal i try  to have have high availability environment Incas if CM 1 down we can user CM 2

Comment: What is the error you are getting for the Experience Analytics on your new server sitecore instance

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at these below options for your new CM2 instance.

1) Please check the self-signed certificate has been installed in your new server. The SOLR instance is running up with the https certificate.

2) Your xconnect website `https://xp0.xconnect/` should be running up with self signed https certificate.

3) Sometimes also seen that the xconnect website faces a trust issue due to the presence of non-self signed certificate in trusted root certificates in MMC.
In power shell administrator mode try to run below command to check how many certificate are in trusted root folder .

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}
```

Try to move them to CA

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-
Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

4) Type mmc and open your Certificate Store for 'Local Computer'. Right-click your `Sitecore certificate > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys`. Grant full control to both NETWORK SERVICE and `IIS_IUSRS`. Do it for both `xp0.xconnect` and `xp0.xconnect_client` certificates.

5) In IIS Manager check the certificate is set for xConnect websites. Set the correct certificate from the list for xconnect website.
[image]

6) There might be certificate thumbprint value mismatched, please check xconnect and sitecore instance website certificate thumbprint value, try to place the correct thumbprint value in the intepub xconnect website App_Config folder `appsetting.config` , `connectionstring.config` and also in the sitecore app_config folder's config files . In case you have created a new certificate and their old certificate thumbprint values are present in that result it can show you an exception.

```
<add key="validateCertificateThumbprint" value="[CORRECT THUMBPRINT VALUE]" />
<add key="AllowInvalidClientCertificates" value="true" />
<add name="xconnect.collection.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=[CORRECT THUMBPRINT VALUE]" />
```

7) Check in the IIS xconnect application pool the identity is set to 'NETWORK SERVICE' also, the xconnect website SSL settings for the content of website or application require SSL checkbox is set to true and client certified is accepted

Finally also please check if there any internal/external network setting is applied which might be also blocked TSL/SSL secure channel communication.

Try to clear your browser cache and reload analytics dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there any proxy that comes into the picture? I have faced such a situation where we had to add the XConnect URL to the Proxy By-pass, hence thought of sharing that info with you.
2. Also, are you using App Pool Identity or a Network user in the App pool of the website. If you are using a Network User, you will need to add that user to the Certificate as well.